# access to /tmp or other temporary file structure in Serverless Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

### AWS Lambda Function Using Console

In AWS Lambda, my Function would save a file from S3 to the `/tmp` directory like so:

```
local_filepath = '/tmp/file.txt'

s3.download_file(
  Bucket=bucket,
  Key=key,
  Filename=local_filepath
)
```

and life was good.

### AWS Lambda Function Using Serverless

Using Serverless however is a different story.

The same setup results in the following error:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/processed.txt.7E4850BD'`

So I would guess there is no `/tmp` dir in the Serverless execution env.

I've tried to just save the file to the current directory, with `local_filepath = 'file.txt'`, but I get a `OSError(30, 'Read-only file system')` error.

Comment: Can you share the full code? You should be able to write to `/tmp` with Serverless, it's the same lambda environment. It seems like there's something in your code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the `tempfile` module, it has a collection of techs to retrieve a temporary directory to use:

```
local_filepath = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'file.txt')
```